# How save xml in node with cdata in php?

Tags: php, xml, cdata

how can I save an xml inside a node of another xml with cdata?

```
   $cddatacom = $xmlDoc->createCDATASection($arraydata['comprobante']); 
    $root = $xmlDoc->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("autorizacion"));
    $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("estado",$arraydata['estado']));
    $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("numeroAutorizacion",$arraydata['numeroAutorizacion']));
    $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("fechaAutorizacion",$arraydata['fechaAutorizacion']));
    $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("ambiente",$arraydata['ambiente']));
    $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("comprobante",$arraydata['comprobante']));
    $root->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement("compro",$cddatacom));
    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
```

Display this error

```
Object of class DOMCdataSection could not be converted to string
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the tag of the programming language you are using.

Comment: The code I'm programming with is php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, next I put how I created the document

```
    $comprobante=$xml->createElement("comprobante");
    $autorizacion->appendChild($comprobante);

    $comprobanteCDATA = $xml->createCDATASection($Dcomprobante); 
    $comprobante->appendChild($comprobanteCDATA);
```

That's it.